# I am getting a null pointer exception with this line of code: cse.opportunity__r.id = opp.opportunityid; cse.account.id = opp.opportunity.accountid;

Tags: null-pointer

I am trying to set the created case account to the opportunitylineitem.opportunity.account and the opportunity__c (lookup on opportunity) to the opportunitylineitem.opportunity.  I am getting a null-pointer exception.  I have tried checking if the list is not empty as well as try-catch exception. Please help.  Code:

```
trigger eOneCaseCreate on OpportunityLineItem (after insert, after update) {

List<opportunitylineitem>opps=[Select id, Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.Description, opportunity.account.accountnumber, Opportunityid, Implementation_Requires_Master_Ticket__c, opportunity.accountid from opportunitylineitem where id in: Trigger.new];

For(OpportunityLineItem opp:opps)
     {

    //System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG,'Step 3'+act.RecordTypeID); 

    if(opp.Implementation_Requires_Master_Ticket__c == true) {

Case cse = new Case();

        cse.RecordTypeId = '012g0000000DG74';
        cse.status = 'In Queue';
        cse.Sub_Status__c = 'Awaiting Contract Processing';
        cse.origin = 'Contract';
        cse.priority = 'P3- Medium';

        try {

           cse.opportunity__r.id = opp.opportunityid;
           cse.account.id = opp.opportunity.accountid; // Causes a   NullPointerException
        } catch(NullPointerException npe) {
           System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + npe.getMessage());
        }

        if(!opps.isEmpty()) {
            cse.opportunity__r.id = opp.opportunityid;
            cse.account.id = opp.opportunity.accountid;}
        cse.subject = opp.opportunity.name;
        cse.description = opp.opportunity.description;
        //cse.Partner_Account__c = opp.opportunity.Partner_Account__c;


            if(!opps.isEmpty()) { 
           cse.type ='New Account Services';

      }
      else {cse.type = 'Add Service';

          } 
        insert cse;


   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Is your RecordTypeID Correct?  ... You shouldn't be doing it that way though

Comment: Not to mention that you're doing the insert inside of a For loop rather than adding cse to a list, then checking to see if it's empty() before doing the insert which is why you could be inserting a null cse that you've just declared as new.

Comment: Try to assign to cse.AccountId instead of to cse.Account.Id

Comment: I made changes as suggested but still having same error

Comment: List<case> newopplist = new list<case>();
    For(OpportunityLineItem opp:opps)
         {
        if(opp.Implementation_Requires_Master_Ticket__c == true) {
            Case cse = new Case();
            cse.opportunity__r.id = opp.opportunityid;
              } 
            newopplist.add(cse);        
        }
       }
       if(newopplist.isEmpty())                   
                  {
                  insert newopplist;
                  }                 
              //excerpt of changes. issue is still with  cse.opportunity__r.id = opp.opportunityid

Answer (score 0):

Had a typo with the api field name.  Its working fine.  Just adding it to my learning pains.